# nose2 with such DSL does not find tests

Tags: python, python-unittest, nose2

This might be really stupid, but I can't get it to work...
I'm want to use the `such` DLS in `nose2` with python 2.7 in Linux.
I'm trying out the beginning of the example from the documentation http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/such_dsl.html (see code below) but it doesn't run the tests, no matter how I launch it from the command line.

My file is called test_something.py, it's the only file in the directory.
I've tried running from the command line with `>> nose2` and `>> nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.layers`, but I always get `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`. With `>> nose2 --plugin layers` I get `ImportError: No module named layers`.

How am I supposed to run this test from the command line??
Thanks!

Code below:

```
import unittest
from nose2.tools import such

with such.A("system with complex setup") as it:
    @it.has_setup
    def setup():
        print "Setup"
        it.things = [1]

    @it.has_teardown
    def teardown():
        print "Teardown"
        it.things = []

    @it.should("do something")
    def test():
        print "Test"
        assert it.things
        it.assertEqual(len(it.things), 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH!
I forgot to add `it.createTests(globals())` at the end of the file!